# Photo inside vCard inside QR code: How to make it readable?

Tags: photo, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I am trying to create a QR code containing my vCard with an inline, Base64 encoded photo in PNG. (I am not interested in a photo referenced by a URI.)

I have studied [vCard 3.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2426), [vCard 4.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350) and Wikipedia articles "vCard" and "Base64".

I have created many vCards:

- versions 2.1, 3.0, 4.0
- photo as PNG or JPEG (just in case PNG does not work)
- with and without line folding in Base64 photo
- with and without diacritics in my contact details

Example:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N;CHARSET=UTF-8:Diblík;Petr
FN;CHARSET=UTF-8:Petr Diblík
TITLE;CHARSET=UTF-8:přední český mozaikář
NICKNAME:pd#
TEL;TYPE=cell:+420777282921
EMAIL:petr.diblik@mozaikar.cz
URL:http://www.mozaikar.cz
PHOTO;TYPE=PNG;ENCODING=B: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
END:VCARD
```

Some of the vCards (not encoded in a QR code yet) can be successfully imported to Google Contacts, including the photo.

But when encoded in a QR code (using goqr.me or qrcode-monkey.com), the vCard is always read WITHOUT the photo, using any of the following QR code readers for Android:

- Google Goggles
- QR Code Reader (Scan, Inc.)
- Seznam.cz qr ctecka (Seznam.cz, a.s.)

(QR Code Desktop Reader (CodeTwo) for Windows cannot read those QR codes at all.)

Please advise how to improve the vCard so as it can be read from a QR code and saved to contacts INCLUDING the photo.

Or if the vCard is valid, is there some combination of a platform (no matter whether desktop or mobile), a QR code reader and a contact manager sw that can do that?

Comment: Did anyone ever find a way to make this work?

Comment: @SeaDude Yes, I found a solution myself and posted it as an answer in 3/2016. But it was deleted by a moderator in 12/2020. The answer basically was to use NeoReader QR & Barcode Scanner. It worked for me with Samsung Galaxy S4 mini at that time. It may not be a universal solution though.

Comment: What did you ultimately use for the `PHOTO:` property of the VCard? I've tried all sorts of variations (B64 encoding of photo, hosting at URL, etc.), none seem to work.

Comment: I used basically what you see in the example in the question above, with 2 differences: swapped order of `ENCODING` and `TYPE`, a photo of size 1144 B (i.e. 858 B before encoding to Base64). I'm afraid though that the non-functional reading can be caused by the QR reader and/or the contacts app you use.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try a smaller image and reordering the PHOTO properties. I'm shooting for iOS built in QR reader in the Camera app.

Comment: After resizing the image down to 96px_x_96px and lowering the PNG export quality way down, I can get the B64 added to the QR (char limit was ~2500 chars in my case), but it is not read by iOS. Hm...